# lgamma function out of range warning

Tags: r, optimization, statistics, scientific-computing

In my project, I need to use lgamma function to calculate very large numbers. But R always shows an error message:value out of range in `lgamma`. For instance:

```
lgamma(exp(1000))
#[1] Inf
#Warning message:
#value out of range in 'lgamma'
```

Is there any approach to solve this problem?

Comment: "always" means that regardless of function?

Comment: The problem is not `lgamma`, but the number you are passing to it. `exp(1000)` is too big a number to be dealt by a `numeric` R value. Try `exp(1000)` to see that actually you are passing `Inf` to `lgamma`.

Comment: then how should I solve this? How should I deal with exp(large numbers)?

Comment: The gamma function is of course related to factorials; and the factorial of exp(1000) is going to be vastly too large a number to do anything with using floating point numbers, especially since even just exp(1000) is too big.  Taking the log will help, but not by enough - `lgamma(exp(703))` is already `1.430072e+308`, pushing right up against the edge of the largest representable double precision float.  You're probably going to have to re-cast your calculation to avoid directly needing such numbers, use symbolic methods, or special-purpose quad- or arbitrary-precision numerical libraries.

Comment: The Rmpfr-package can probably help work with larger numbers

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach that you can consider :

```
lgamma_Approx1 <- function(z)
{
  term1 <- 1 / 2 * (log(2 * pi) - log(z))
  term2 <- z * (log(z + 1 / (12 * z - 1 / (10 * z))) - 1)
  val <- term1 + term2
  return(val)
}

lgamma_Approx2 <- function(z)
{
  term1 <- 1 / 2 * (log(2 * pi) - log(z))
  term2 <- z * (log(z) - 1)
  val <- term1 + term2
  return(val)
}

val <- 1000
lgamma(val)
 5905.22
lgamma_Approx1(val)
 5905.22
lgamma_Approx2(val)
 5905.22

library(Rmpfr)
num <- as.bigz(10)
num <- num ^ 350
lgamma_Approx2(num)

Big Integer ('bigz') :
[1] 80399999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999598
```